# How to disable explicit type highlight in Visual Studio Code for C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, highlight, omnisharp

I installed a new version of the C# extension for Visual Studio Code, and it started to provide highlights inline for explicit typing.

How can I disable this without reverting the extension to an older version?

[image: underlined inline highlight in c# code example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to disable the "Inlay Hints" options.  I think you want to disable a few:

- `csharp.inlayHints.enableInlayHintsForTypes`
- `csharp.inlayHints.enableInlayHintsForImplicitObjectCreation`
- `csharp.inlayHints.enableInlayHintsForLambdaParameterTypes`
- `csharp.inlayHints.enableInlayHintsForImplicitVariableTypes`

Settings JSON:

```json
{
  "csharp.inlayHints.enableInlayHintsForTypes": false,
  "csharp.inlayHints.enableInlayHintsForImplicitObjectCreation": false,
  "csharp.inlayHints.enableInlayHintsForLambdaParameterTypes": false,
  "csharp.inlayHints.enableInlayHintsForImplicitVariableTypes": false
}
```

Search "inlay" in the settings and go to the C# tab and you can find all of the various inlay options:

[image: c# inlay hint options]